# Are questions "What caveats are there when implementing X in a programming language?" on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I asked [one such question](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/q/1469/330) and it got downvoted.

Comment: isn't this essentially just asking about the cons instead of pros and cons? see https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=pros%20and%20cons%20is%3aq&searchOn=3